# Installation of RAD 10.4

Tags: delphi

Can I install  RAD 10.4  (Delphi , C++)  from *.iso  file via an batch file on a new computer
Licence file *.slip  is also available

why :  automatic client computer config  without  manual  interaction

Comment: Worst case scenario, use AutoHotkey instead?

Comment: You *could* write a batch file to do this, yes.

Comment: If you just need the compilers, but not the IDE (e.g. for a build machine) you can just copy the bin folder to the target system, and run dcc32/dcc64 executables.

Answer (score 3):

## Update

For RAD Studio (Delphi and CBuilder) 10.4.2 Sydney silent installation mode was [reintroduced](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-10-4-2-silent-installer-makes-it-easy-automate-the-installation-process/):

> | Command | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `/SILENT` | Runs the installer in silent mode. The progress window is displayed. |
> | `/VERYSILENT` | Runs the installer in very silent mode. No windows are displayed. |
> | `/SUPRESSMSGBOXES` | Suppresses messagge boxes. This has an effect only when combined with `/SILENT` and `/VERYSILENT`. |
> | `/NOCANCEL` | Disables canceling the installation process. |
> | `/NORESTART` | Prevents the installer from restarting the system even if it is necessary. |
> | `/DIR="x:dirpath"` | Overrides the default install directory. |
> | `/SLIPFILE="x:filepath"` | Installs a license file. |
> | `/FEATURES=featureid` | Indicates the feature(s) to install, separated with ” ; “. See the list below for the available features’ names. |
> | `/LOG="x:filepath"` | Causes setup to create a log file for debugging the installation process. If the file cannot be created, Setup will abort with an error message. |

> **Note**: A license file should be installed on the target machine before silently installing RAD Studio or you can install it using the `/SLIPFILE` option.

> | Feature ID | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | delphi | Installs all Delphi platforms |
> | delphi_windows | Installs Delphi Windows platform |
> | delphi_macos | Installs Delphi macOS platform |
> | delphi_linux | Installs Delphi Linux platform |
> | delphi_ios | Installs Delphi iOS platform |
> | delphi_android | Installs Delphi Android platform |
> | cbuilder | Installs all C++ Builder platforms |
> | cbuilder_windows | Installs C++ Builder Windows platform |
> | cbuilder_ios | Installs C++ Builder iOS platform |
> | cbuilder_android | Installs C++ Builder Android platform |
> | french | Installs French language pack |
> | german | Installs German language pack |
> | japanese | Installs Japanese language pack |
> | samples | Installs Samples |
> | help | Installs Help files |
> | teechart | Installs TeeChart components |
> | dunit | Installs DUnit components |
> | interbase_express | Installs InterBase Express components |
> | interbase_2020 | Installs InterBase 2020 |
> | openjdk | Installs AdoptOpenJDK |
> | android_sdk | Installs AndroidSDK |

**Example**

> `rad_studio_example_setup.exe /VERYSILENT /FEATURES=delphi;cbuilder`

### End of update

Unfortunately, the answer is no (before version `10.4.2`)!
The installer does not support an automatic / unattended installation.

I got this information directly from Embarcadero support a few years ago for an older version.
[Here](https://www.delphipraxis.net/1450737-post2.html) is a more recent information from Embarcadero Germany.

For the record:
It was [possible for Delphi 2007](https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/07/unattended-delphi-installation-how.html), e.g.

Comment: read  this  first and follow  link  given here :  https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/3732-offline-installer-getit-doesnt-work-with-msg-json-metadata-not-found/

Comment: see Offline Installer  : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Release_Notes
Download the installer and the.gof file to the same folder
Start the installler
It will automatically detect the offline mode and it will use the offline image to install the RAD Studio features.

If you use the offline installer, RAD Studio will not be able to access the GetIt Package Manager until you manually switch to "online mode". To do this, we recommend using the GetItCmd.exe tool: GetItCmd.exe -c=useonline

Comment: So what? This has nothing to do with your q about installing without interaction!